# Sum of two random variables (General Formula)

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, random-variables, soft-question, convolution

> Rather than attempt to derive a general expression for the
> distribution of $X + Y$ in the discrete case, we shall consider some
> examples. ([Ross, A First Course in Probability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9353065607), Section 6.3.4)

The examples in the book are sum of two

- Binomial random variables : itself a Binomial
- Poisson random variables: itself a Poisson.

Is there anywhere else I should look for further details on the topic? Or is the general formula too difficult/not important?

Comment: The point is merely, that not all of the distributions lead to nice, explicit expressions for the sum. Poisson and Binomial (for fixed p) are examples of so call convolution half groups. A topic related is "infinitely divisible distributions". However, this demands a rather deep level of understanding in probability theory.

Comment: The distribution of the sum of two independent random variables should coincide with the convolution of the distributions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_convolutions_of_probability_distributions

Comment: I know it is the convolution. Ross mentions this.

Comment: @PeterStrouvelle in which subject would one study infinite divisibility? stochastic processes?

Comment: In Lévy Processes, for example.

Comment: So basically, as a part of stochastic processes